# Automatic USB Formatter: Linux

Tags: command-line, script, formatting, raspberry-pi, raspbian

How can I automatically format a USB when I put it in a Raspberry Pi that is running Raspbian?

This question was previouly posted by me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120420/automatic-usb-formatter-linux.

However it was put on hold and I was told to come here.

Comment: How do you do any task automatically in linux?

Cron!.

Comment: `cron` is for scheduling tasks to run periodically; that's probably not what you want.  you want to trigger a script via hardware change; that's more of a job for `udev`.

Comment: I think you should write [a `udev` rule](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28548/108618) that executes a script where `sfdisk` and/or `mkfs` do their jobs. I cannot elaborate, I have never done this. General advice: test your solution without actual formatting and make sure it doesn't kick in during reboot to target your SD card or something else.

Comment: Definitely sounds risky, like making an "automatic data destroyer box". There's also a raspberry pi SE site here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have figured out how to format the drive with a python script. The next step is trying to figure out how to launch a script when a USB is plugged in. I am trying to use a udev rule this is what I currently have: Action=="add", SUBSYSEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", SYMLINK=="usbflash", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="home/pi/Desktop/test.sh". This however is not working when a USB is inserted.